# Trying to Create a Preset in AI That Gives Object Strokes a Hand Drawn, Blueprint Drafting Sketch Style

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, graphic-styles

I've been working on a few logo ideas for a friend's company in my spare time; for one of them I wanted to have the logo look like it was sketched out first and then given an outline - like it's a drafting sketch (see the attached photo).[image: A close-up of part of the logo]

I did it by splitting the logo up at it's corners, lengthening the line segments and applying one of several "sketched lines" brushes I made.  While this achieved the desired affect it wasn't the most elegant solution.  Now I'd like to try duplicating this effect on text but I'd prefer to do it by creating a graphic style (or another type of preset like a brush) so I can test it out on different fonts without spending hours working with each individual line myself.  The problem I kept running into is at the corners where the sketch lines continue past the connecting perpendicular line; I can't think of a way to create that effect without splitting up the object and extending the lines.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution may be a **Scatter Brush**.

If you create a "sketchy" brush as a **Scatter Brush** then set it to be **relative to the path**, you can get close. Every corner looks similar, but I think this is as close as you can get with any sort of "automated" method.

Add an additional stroke and apply the scatter brush. Without the base stroke you get a very patterned, choppy, base path. (Scribble on the base path may help as well.)

[image]
<sub>Right-click/Control-click and choose `open image in new window/tab` to see it larger</sub>

This is quick and dirty, without any great refinement. And there are areas of concern, like that odd rotation on the corner of the T. But it looks to be a promising method to explore. I can't think of any way, other than brushes, to get overshot corners without cutting paths.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  It was one of the first things I thought might work, and I did try to create a scatter brush but with horrible results - probably because it was the first time I'd ever made one myself.  The issues with using a scatter brush that you mentioned, like the corners all looking the same, I sort of figured would be unavoidable unless there's some way to randomize different pieces of the brush (and I don't think there is).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You cna only randomize *how* the same piece is used, not pieces themselves. Randomizing the scale would allow for *some* appearance changes but is highly dependent upon the brush used.

Comment: The result you got is way better than the one I did.  If you don't mind, would you be willing to post some screen caps of the object you turned into a scatter brush, how you segmented it and which slot you placed the segments into?  And thank you for your response, I really appreciate it!

Comment: [Here's a blow up of the brush art](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KdYHn.jpg) I just applied the stock "Charcoal feather" brush to a path, expanded it, then deleted a bunch. Leaving the tiny bits spread out helps a bit with positioning, but that's also why some corners weren't getting any visual change. With Scatter brushes there are no "segments' it's 1 element, similar to calligraphy brushes.

Comment: Here's a link to the AI CC2014 file: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/490632/Scatter%20type.ai.zip (Sorry for the horrible free file host). You probably won't have the font, but you can at least examine the brush I used if needed.

Comment: Oh, I guess I did also add some random horizontal strokes to the brush art using the blob brush to make it a bit more solid. Then selected all and pathfinder > unite to get to a solid shape.